# Admob Interstitial ad size isn't right

Tags: ios, admob

Admob interstitials should be full-screen. But, some of the interstitials shown are n't covering the whole screen.

[image: Interstitial not covering the whole screen]

I am using admob's latest iOS SDK.

The view debugger shows this ad is presented using webview.

[image: View Debugger]

Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would had commented this but I don't have enough reputation.

The dimension of the app is determined by the advertiser. By selecting a interstitial ad you are actually making the whole screen available for the advertiser but it is the advertiser who decides how much space it gonna use.

The cancel button on the right upper corner proves my point, it is outside the actual advertisement so the whole screen is actually used.